# Applications for removable media don't run when screen is blanked

Tags: gnome, power-management, usb-drive, screensaver

I have used the Devices / Removable Media settings to activate a CD playing program when an audio CD is inserted. Works fine, except… when screen is blanked. I have the screen set to be blanked after a few minutes in the Power settings (because I'm using an OLED screen, where there is danger of burn-in), and when the screen is blank, apparently the selected removable media applications don't get activated. Is there any way to change this behavior? (The screen is not relevant for playing a CD!)

An alternative approach I've tried is to not use the Gnome screen blanking feature but xcsreensaver instead, and that works, but has another issue that I haven't been able to fix: xscreensaver gets activated when I'm watching a movie in VLC, and neither ticking “disable screensaver” in VLC nor running caffeine has any effect on that. (I've looked at related issues on this site but none has helped.) So I'd prefer to use the Gnome screen blanking, which doesn't activate when I'm watching a movie.

I have verified that it's not the CD playing that won't start, but the activation that doesn't happen. (I tried replacing the application with a script launcher that just writes something to a file when it's run, and that happens when the screen is not blanked, but not when the screen is blanked.)

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (with Gnome 3.28.2).

Answer (score 0):

No answers here, so I went for fixing the problem with xscreensaver instead. I had to write a little replacement script for caffeine to get it to work. [Can be found here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/caffeine/+bug/1768801/comments/7).